# How to ccompile C socket programming on my mobile phone using c4droid?

Tags: c

I wrote a simple client-server code on my laptop and it works fine .... can same client code can run on c4droid in my mobile phone, without any changes??

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: @immibis i tried now but its not working. Though the code is compiling fine without error, but when i try to run it. Its not connecting.